# gulp.src() not reading required JSON file's array values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to get `gulp.src()` to stream files from an array, so I can use gulp-inject to write them to my index.html file. Listed below is my `gulp.config.json` file which will hold the file paths of the packages included in my project.

```
{
    "vendorjs": [
        "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "angular/angular.js",
        "ng-token-auth/dist/ng-token-auth.js",
        "angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
        "ngInfiniteScroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js",
        "js/vendor/angular-ui-tour.js",
        "spin.js/spin.js",
        "angular-spinner/angular-spinner.min.js",
        "angular-scroll/angular-scroll.js"
    ],
    "js": [
        "js/app.js",
        "js/directives.js",
        "js/services.js",
        "js/filters.js"
    ]
}
```

my gulpfile.js looks like this for debugging purposes
**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    paths = require('./gulp.config.json'),
    debug = require('gulp-debug');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.vendorjs).pipe(debug());
});
```

and it only seems to output to the console:
`gulp-debug: js/vendor/angular-ui-tour.js`

that is unless I switch `paths.vendorjs` to `paths.js` like so: `gulp.src(paths.js).pipe(debug())` and then I get output for every file in the js array

```
gulp-debug: js/app.js
gulp-debug: js/directives.js
gulp-debug: js/services.js
gulp-debug: js/filters.js
```

Could someone please clarify why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the paths for all the files except for the one displayed are not correct so they don't enter into the pipe. You can use something like gulp-expect-file to check if all the files have entered to the pipe.

Comment: So the paths in the array actually have to match a file in the project?  I was under the impression it would be a 'path in path out' situation since I'm not actually doing anything with the paths aside from using their names.

Comment: Yes, those files have to exist at that location, gulp will take those files and run them through a series of transformations and then write them with gulp.dest. If the file doesn't exist nothing is happening.

Comment: Is there a way to get gulp to ignore finding them and just use the names, or do I have to add, `../../components/bower_components` to all of my file paths?

Comment: it does ignore them, there is nothing happening to them. The gulp.src is meant to take a list of files, it can't take a list of strings. But what are you trying to accomplish? What would be your main goal with gulp?