# gulp concat javascript files in order same as in index.html

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-useref

I would like use [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) for concant js files in same order as in index.html.

Solution has this structure:

- Solution Folder

  - App Folder

    - Services Folder

      - service.js
  - Scripts Folder

    - angular.js

**index.html**

```
<script src = "scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src = "app/services/service.js"></script>
```

**Gulp**

```
gulp.src("index.html")
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(concant("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + "/app"));
```

When I run this gulp task app.js file is created but contains content of index.html.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: There is an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386940/why-does-gulp-src-not-like-being-passed-an-array-of-complete-paths-to-files