# Array path not working with gulp.task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I have a gulp task that concats and uglifies the js files when changed. If I only use one source, it works. I am learning angular however, and want it to concat the modules first so similar to this:

https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917#.mujtfmj63

I am using:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src(path.gulp.paths.src + ['/**/module.js', '/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.gulp.paths.dist));
  });
```

and the gulp task runs but it does not create the all.min.js file. If I remove the array and just use this it works:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src(path.gulp.paths.src + '/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.gulp.paths.dist));
  });
```

My directory is set up as

```
public
 |  
 +-- modules
 |  |  
 |  +-- module.js
 +-- test.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386940/why-does-gulp-src-not-like-being-passed-an-array-of-complete-paths-to-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add `path.gulp.paths.src` (which I assume is a string) to an array. For this operation, JavaScript first converts the array to a string (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124907). Assuming your string is `'./public'`, what you end up passing to `gulp.src` is `'./public/**/module.js,/**/*.js'`, which is not a valid path.

You could prepend the string to each element of the array (`[path.gulp.paths.src + '/**/module.js', path.gulp.paths.src + '/**/*.js']`), or you can use the [`cwd` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs#optionscwd) to just set it as the base for all your files:

```
return gulp.src(['/**/module.js', '/**/*.js'], {cwd: path.gulp.paths.src})
...
```