# Images not being outputted to destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp

New to gulp. Is there anything wrong with my code? The images should be output to:
`assets/images/` but they are not being moved.

My code looks like this:

```
const FILES_IMAGES = ['./src/components/**/img/*.{svg,jpg,png,gif,jpg}'];
const ASSETS_PATH = '../server/assets/';
const ASSETS_IMG_PATH = ASSETS_PATH + 'images/';

/*
 * Images
 * --
 * Move and Compress images
 */
gulp.task('images', function () {
    gulp.src(FILES_IMAGES)
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: 1 }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(ASSETS_IMG_PATH))
    ;
});

...more code

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'css', 'css.min', 'images']);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would try flatten() with no argument and ASSETS_IMG_PATH = 'assets/images'.  flatten() will get rid of all parent directories.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try here:

1. Try returning from the task to tell the task system when the task is finished, because `gulp.src` is async, more on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21700789/6053299):

   ```
   gulp.task('images', function () {
       return gulp.src(FILES_IMAGES)
           .pipe(imagemin())
           .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: 1 }))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(ASSETS_IMG_PATH));
   });
   ```
2. Try sending a `string` instead of an `array` into `gulp.src`, more on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21387311/6053299):

`const FILES_IMAGES = './src/components/**/img/*.{svg,jpg,png,gif,jpg}';`

3. If sending an `array` into `gulp.src` (as it is now), try specifying `base` directory in `gulp.src`, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21387311/6053299) might also help:

`gulp.src(FILES_IMAGES, {base: "."})`

I would guess the first point or combination of the first and second points would do the trick.