# Gulp task publishing only one project

Tags: msbuild, gulp, sitecore-habitat

When trying to publish projects from a solution using the below gulp task it working fine.

```
 var publish = function (projectPath) {
return gulp.src([projectPath + "/**/*.csproj"])
    .pipe(foreach(function (stream, file) {
        return publishStream(stream, file);
    }));
```

But when I pass an array with my project name in to gulp.src like below, publishing only one project and the task is exited. (here 'projects' is my array of projects)

```
return gulp.src(projects)
    .pipe(foreach(function (stream, file) {
        return publishStream(stream, file);
    }));
```

What may be the reason

Comment: Changed tag 'habitat' to 'sitecore-habitat'. Part of effort to split up ambiguous tag 'habitat'

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the root folder as second parameter as shown below.

```
gulp.src(['bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
            'bower_components/superscrollorama/js/greensock/TweenMax.min.js',
            'bower_components/superscrollorama/jquery.superscrollorama.js' ],
        {base: 'bower_components/'})
    .pipe(...);
```

Please have a look at [Why does gulp.src not like being passed an array of complete paths to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386940/why-does-gulp-src-not-like-being-passed-an-array-of-complete-paths-to-files).